# Machine Learning - Correlação baixa com o target

Tags: python, data, pandas, ciência-de-dados, jupyter-notebook

Tenho um problema de regressão linear múltipla pra realizar previsões, porém todas as minhas variáveis tem uma correlação baixa com a variável target.

- Isso acaba afetando na hora da previsão?
- Tem algo que possa fazer para aumentar essa correlação?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -3):

A correlação entre as variáveis independentes (também chamadas de explicativas ou preditoras) e a variável dependente (também chamada de resposta ou target) é importante em uma análise de regressão linear múltipla, pois quanto maior a correlação, maior é a capacidade de previsão do modelo. Se as variáveis independentes tiverem uma correlação baixa com a variável dependente, o modelo pode ter uma precisão baixa na previsão.

Existem algumas coisas que você pode fazer para aumentar a correlação entre as variáveis independentes e a variável dependente:

Selecionar variáveis independentes mais relevantes: você pode remover variáveis independentes que não têm uma forte correlação com a variável dependente, ou seja, que não contribuem significativamente para a previsão.

Transformar as variáveis independentes: as transformações, como a logaritimização, podem ajudar a aumentar a correlação entre as variáveis independentes e a variável dependente.

Adicionar novas variáveis independentes: se você tiver informações adicionais que possam ser relevantes para a previsão, pode ser útil adicioná-las ao modelo como novas variáveis independentes.

Usar técnicas de seleção de características: essas técnicas, como a seleção de recursos de árvores de decisão, podem ajudar a selecionar as variáveis independentes mais relevantes para o modelo.

Usar modelos de regressão não lineares: em alguns casos, um modelo de regressão linear múltipla pode não ser a melhor opção. Em vez disso, você pode considerar usar um modelo de regressão não linear, como a regressão polinomial, que pode ser mais adequado para um conjunto de dados com uma correlação baixa.

No geral, é importante lembrar que a correlação não é a única medida de quão bem um modelo de regressão linear múltipla pode prever a variável dependente. Outros fatores, como o erro de residência e o erro padrão, também devem ser levados em consideração ao avaliar o desempenho do modelo.

Comment: muito obrigado,ficou muito bem explicado e irei pesquisar mais sobre a regressão não linear,para aplica-lá